# NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302: Image source not readable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I trying to follow tutorial about insert image and resize it, but i facing one problem showing image source not readable.

I am using PHP, Laravel 5 framework and mysql. When I run my code i stop on `Image::make`

Here is my controller code:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\FoodRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Photo;
use Image;
use App\Restaurant;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

public function addPhoto($zip, $street, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'photo' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp'
    ]);
    $photo = $this->makePhoto($request->file('photo'));
    Restaurant::locatedAt($zip, $street)->addPhoto($photo);
}

protected function makePhoto(UploadedFile $file)
{
    return Photo::named($file->getClientOriginalName())
        ->move($file);
}
```

Here is Photo Code:

```
public static function named($name)
{
    return (new static)->saveAs($name);
}

protected function saveAs($name)
{
    $this->name = sprintf("%s-%s", time(), $name);
    $this->path = sprintf("%s-%s", $this->baseDir, $this->name);
    $this->thumbnail_path = sprintf("%s/tn-%s", $this->baseDir, $this->name);
    return $this;
}

public function move(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $file->move($this->baseDir, $this->name);
    $this->makeThumbnail();
    return $this;
}

protected function makeThumbnail()
{   
    Image::make($this->path)
        ->fit(200)
        ->save($this->thumbnail_path);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example from my own code where I write the path to my pics

```
$destinationpath = 'img/' . $propertyid;
  $frontpage = 'img/' . $propertyid. '/frontpage/' ;
  $gallery =  'img/' . $propertyid. '/gallery/' ;
  $thumbpath = 'img/' .$propertyid .'/thumbnails/';
```

move the image file to a place at which the Intervention Manipulation
 code will process the image, change size etc. We will save the results
 of the processing in their respective folders and then delete this image.

$image->move($destinationpath, $filename );

```
$dbImg = new Picture;

                    $dbImg->property_id = $propertyid;
                    $dbImg->name = $filename;
                    $dbImg->save();
```

Comment: how to do a var_dump can give me an example for var_dump

Comment: finally i found what i am wrong !! Thank you for your advice, because the path name make my code confuse. By the way thank for you suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

I did the same tutorial , you should do this:

```
Image::make($this->path.$this->name)->resize(128, 
    128)->save($this->thumbnail_path.$this->name);
```

instead of doing this:

```
Image::make($this->path)->fit(200)->save($this->thumbnail_path);
```